# Cuando es necesario usar protocolo SSH ? (Python)

Tags: python, ssh

Actualmente me encuentro trabajando en IT y estamos usando el protocolo SSH en ciertas conexiones a bases de datos. Mi duda surgió cuando tuve que realizar la conexión una base de datos mariadb y me dijeron que no teníamos necesidad de usar SSH. Esta es una base de datos de un tercero que nos presta el servicio. Luego tenemos la conexion a un mongodb que esta en una maquina virtual y usamos SSH con una key(entiendo publica) en un path.

Gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Existe la posibilidad de que un tercero intercepte / vea / analice tus mensajes desde y hacia la BD? Si la respuesta es Sí, entonces **debes** usar SSH.

Comment: Además de codificar la información que se transmite, SSH también te permite "tunelizar" la conexión a través de redes inseguras. Entre servidores de tu red interna puede que no haga falta usar SSH, pero sí que es recomendable que las conexiones externas vengan en SSH, si no es directamente al servidor de la base de datos, sí al menos a una máquina de salto que haga de intermediaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta corta: la mayoría de casos si

Respuesta larga:

Todo depende, si la data que manejas es importante y/o no confías mucho en como esta configurado la implementación del servidor de base de datos, usar una conexión por SSHl ademas que oculta el trafico también te protege de que tus atacantes sepan que servicios de BBDD estas usando y te evitan los ataques mas dirigidos.

Siempre vas a encontrar diferentes niveles de protección y todo depende de que tan seguro es tu proveedor o que tan fácil se hace implementar la comunicación ya sea por ssh o incluso VPN siempre que te encuentres ante esas dudas tienes que balancear tu solución basado en:

- importancia de la información
- complejidad de la solución
- performance

pero en conclusion, implementar SSH ayuda en mucho y su implementación casi es indolora contando esos factores no esta de mas usarlo